# Fan switch not working

Tags: dodge, fan

On my 2006 Dodge Ram 1500, my fan switch only has 2 modes now: off and high.  On the low and medium settings the fan turns off. Do I just need to replace the switch or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be a blower motor resistor.

Comment: Any further tips for Tim?  Which resistor would you think would be faulty?

Comment: @Qadaemon Once I locate the blower motor resistor, what's the best way to test it out to make sure that is the problem?

Comment: Just changed the resistor today, that was it. Thanks!